# TFS Warehouse Test Result Stack Trace

Tags: database, testing, tfs

I am able to query the Test Result data for my automated tests in the TFS Warehouse DB using the TestResultView.  However, I haven't been able to determine how to get the Stack Trace data that is reported in the TFS browser result page for failed tests.  Can someone tell me how I can query the TFS Warehouse DB and get the Stack Trace data for an automated test that does an Assert.Fail?  I haven't been able to find the table or column that has this data.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Team Foundation Server 2015

Answer (score 0):

It's suggested using api to get Test Result Stack Trace instead of querying database. You could refer to Results api:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

Comment: I am using SSRS reporting on the database.  I don't know if I can use the REST API inside of reports.

Comment: Since you are using TFS 2015, which doesn't support the REST API above. You would check the case below to use the old api: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152415/getting-the-stacktrace-for-a-testcaseresult-that-failed-in-tfs-via-api

Comment: It would be very challenging to try and do this using SSRS.  Not sure if you can call TFS APIs using SSRS hosted on a report server.  Is this possible?  If so, how is it done?

Comment: You would need to create a solution, using TFS api to get the stack trace and generate your own report.

Comment: That's not really a good solution for what I am doing.  I am using SSRS report server subscriptions to e-mail test reports to stakeholders.  Having a separate application to just get the stack trace is not very practical for my situation.

Comment: Usually, we don't recommend querying database directly, using API is a more safe way.

Comment: I understand that, but unless Microsoft or some other company comes up with a way to do SSRS reporting using the web API, there aren't any other options to write reports unless I take the time to create an application to do the reporting, which would take much longer to implement vs. using Reporting Services.

Comment: Stack Trace information stores in table `[Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_TestResultEx]`, it doesn't exist in TFS Warehouse DB by default.

Comment: Is there a way to get that table data to be stored into the warehouse DB?

Comment: If you want to add new data types to the warehouse you will probably need to create an adapter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/bb130342(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN